# HTML5 Video Slider loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video

I created a webapp in react, and for this app I created an html5 video slider. The slider renders the videos after each other. Since they are in a subcomponent, and the render looks like this:

`if (currentIndex == slideIndex) <Slide />`

it always rerenders the current video.

Sicne the slider is infinite this causes a lot of data usage when you forget the site open and it loads the videos forever.

I was also thinking about removing the conditional rendering, and just play around with the style display property, but I assume it would cause the same issue, or maybe with the opacity of the video, but I feel these are just half solutions.

Is there a common practice to avoid this? Unfortuantely I can't ditch the video slider since this will be a portfolio for a filmmaking company.

Thanks for your anwsers!

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. Could you give more information?

Comment: My problem is, that when react renders a slide, the html5 video starts to load. After the the slide is over, this element is removed, and the next video will render. This creates an infinite loop (which is the expectation) but everytime a video loads, it gets loaded from the server -> causing unnecessery bandwidth usage. My question is how to avoid this. Hope this clarifies my question.